# Show Time Difference Out of Order

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I’d like to get a count of how many times a process code of 20 has a LastModifiedTime before a  process code of 10 for each WorkflowId grouping.

This query shows the table layout and some data:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * 
FROM master.ProcessLogging with (nolock) 
WHERE ProcessCode = 10 OR ProcessCode = 20 
ORDER BY WorkflowId, ProcessCode
```

[image]

I've tried a few things, but I'm having a difficult time getting it to work. Each attempt has lead to a dead end that's not worth posting here. Is there a way to see all of the times a 20 comes before a 10? And maybe even see the time difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon review this will break if more than one 10 in a group

Will there ever be more than 10 in a group and if so how do you want it handled?

```
SELECT p10.WorkflowId, count(p20.WorkflowId)
FROM master.ProcessLogging p10 
left outer join master.ProcessLogging p20
  on  p20.WorkflowId = p10.WorkflowId
  and p20.EventTime < p10.EventTime
  and p20.ProcessCode = 20
where p10.ProcessCode = 10 
group by p10.WorkflowId 
order by p10.WorkflowId
```

-- **Edit from Bob Horn** --

Slightly modified above query to show the largest time difference between the 10s and 20s.

```
SELECT p10.WorkflowId, min(p20.WorkflowId), 
       DATEDIFF(ms, min(p10.lastmodifiedtime), min(p20.lastmodifiedtime)) as 'Diff (ms)'
FROM master.ProcessLogging p10 
join master.ProcessLogging p20
  on  p20.WorkflowId = p10.WorkflowId
  and p20.EventTime < p10.EventTime
  and p20.ProcessCode = 20
where p10.ProcessCode = 10 
group by p10.WorkflowId 
order by ABS(DATEDIFF(ms, min(p10.lastmodifiedtime), min(p20.lastmodifiedtime))) DESC
```

Comment: There will never be more than one 10 in a group. I'm looking into your solution now. Thanks!

Comment: So, basically anything that has a value in column 2 means the 20 came before the 10?

Comment: Yes in p20.WorkflowId and that needs to be count not sum.  The p20.EventTime < p10.EventTime requires before.  Did on outer join so you can get a count of 0.  If you want to exclude the 0 then join rather than left outerjoin

Comment: This works well. All I had to do was add a column to the SELECT list to get the time difference: `DATEDIFF(ms, min(p10.lastmodifiedtime), min(p20.lastmodifiedtime)) as 'Diff (ms)'`. Then I ordered by that to see the worst offenders: `order by ABS(DATEDIFF(ms, min(p10.lastmodifiedtime), min(p20.lastmodifiedtime))) DESC`. Simple and clean. Thanks!

Comment: See you took min(p10.lastmodifiedtime) to deal with more then one 10.  Might be able to take the ABS off and use ASC.

Comment: Actually, there is only ever on 10. I used min because it was the only way I knew to show LastModifiedTime. Min will return the only value that exists.

Comment: Not that you need to change it but you could use p10.lastmodifiedtime if you changed it to group by p10.WorkflowId, p10.lastmodifiedtime.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you could add a [row number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to your query, then wrap it inside a SELECT WHERE PROCESSCODE=20 AND (SELECT PROCESSCODE FROM [same query] WHERE rownumber=rownumber+1)=10. Or something like that. Haven't worked out the details.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
with cte as (
    SELECT *,
        row_number() over (partition by WorkflowId order by ProcessCode) as [a] ,
        row_number() over (partition by WorkflowId order by LastModifiedTime) as [b]
    FROM master.ProcessLogging with (nolock) 
    WHERE ProcessCode = 10 OR ProcessCode = 20 
)
select * from cte
where [a] - [b] <> 0
```

By way of explanation, I'm getting two different rankings for each WorkflowId. If the process codes are in the correct (i.e. ascending) order, then both rankings will be the same and so the difference will be 0. If not, the rankings will be different and the difference of them will be non-zero.

Comment: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

Answer (score 1):

If 20 is always supposed to be last per WorkflowId based on LastModifiedTime, then it is quite simple. You don't even have to look at EventTime. No Row_Number needed:

```
SELECT *
FROM
   master.ProcessLogging L
WHERE
   L.ProcessCode = 20
   AND EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM master.ProcessLogging L2
      WHERE
         L.WorkflowId = L2.WorkflowId
         AND L.LastModifiedTime < L2.LastModifiedTime
         AND L2.ProcessCode = 10
   )
```

This will return one row per out-of-order workflow, so you can easily change it to `SELECT Count(*)` instead of `SELECT *`.

If EventTime also became significant, you could just add that to the exists clause as an OR with the LastModifiedTime as well.

I just noticed you wanted the time difference between them (which by showing detail per row means you can't return a single count). Here's a query that can do this in SQL 2005 and up. If you are using anything less than SQL Server 2005, please let us know and I will write you a different query.

```
SELECT
   *,
   MinutesApart = DateDiff(minute, L.LastModifiedTime, L2.LastModifiedTime)
FROM
   master.ProcessLogging L
   CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT TOP 1 *
      FROM master.ProcessLogging L2
      WHERE
         L.WorkflowId = L2.WorkflowId
         AND L.LastModifiedTime < L2.LastModifiedTime
         AND L2.ProcessCode = 10
      ORDER BY L2.LastModifiedTime DESC
   ) L2
WHERE
   L.ProcessCode = 20
```

Note that if you have multiple 10 codes after the 20, this will only show the worst one. To see all of them (and get multiple rows per 20 code) you can change this to a simple self-join:

```
SELECT
   *,
   MinutesApart = DateDiff(minute, L.LastModifiedTime, L2.LastModifiedTime)
FROM
   master.ProcessLogging L
   INNER JOIN master.ProcessLogging L2
      ON L.WorkflowId = L2.WorkflowId
WHERE
   L.ProcessCode = 20
   AND L2.ProcessCode = 10
   AND L.LastModifiedTime < L2.LastModifiedTime
```

Comment: 20 is *supposed* to be last, but that's not always the case. That's why I need this query. :)

Comment: Then I eagerly await your verdict as to whether my queries will fit the bill.

Comment: If my queries are not returning exactly what you want to see, please provide detail and I will give provide versions that do.

Comment: Will do. I have quite a few options to try now. I'm going through all of them and I'll reply. Thanks!

Comment: +1 because it worked well. I chose Blam's answer because it was the simplest and cleanest. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! It would have helped to know exactly what output you wanted, then I could have zeroed in on it immediately. :)

Comment: That's a good point. I'll remember that for future posts. It's nice that there are people like you that are this enthusiastic about helping.